# Start Stop Shell Script Synology NAS

Tags: shell, sh, synology

I've trouble with a simple start/stop shell script for my Synology DS216play NAS.
I want to assamble and mount a USB-Raid volume at boot and unmound + stop it on shutdown.
According to synology this should be possible: https://developer.synology.com/developer-guide/integrate_dsm/run_with_system_boot.html

So I wrote this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Mount/Unmount USB raid volume

case “$1” in
    start)
        echo "Mounting USB Raid"
        cp /volume1/.config/mdadm.conf /etc
        mdadm -A /dev/md123
        sleep 1
        mount /dev/md123 /volume1/Media
        ;;
    stop)
        echo "Unmounting USB Raid"  
        umount /dev/md123
        sleep 1
        mdadm --stop /dev/md123
        sleep 1
        rm /etc/madm.conf
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: "$1" {start|stop}"
        exit 1
esac
exit 0
```

But it allways endup with case *

```
$ ./mount-usb-raid.sh stop
Usage: stop {start|stop}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
case “$1” in
```

That should be

```
case "$1" in
```

I.e. use ASCII quotes (`"`) instead of fancy Unicode quotes (`“`, `”`).

Also, this line is wrong:

```
        echo "Usage: "$1" {start|stop}"
```

It should be

```
        echo "Usage: $1 {start|stop}"
```

Otherwise `$1` will be left unquoted.